# User to start Passenger (with Nginx)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I have Nginx with Passenger.  In nginx.conf I have line:

```
user pass users;
```

and Nginx process works on 'pass' user, but Passenger* processes work on 'nobody' user.

I can run Passenger standalone:

```
sudo passanger start -e production -p 80 --user=pass
```

How can I run Passenger with Nginx with my custom user?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put the following into your **nginx.conf** in the **http** block:

```
passenger_default_user custom_username;
passenger_default_group custom_group;
```

You can find more configuration options here:

http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerDefaultUser

Answer (score 7):

At one point the user and group were determined by the owners of the config.ru file. I'm pretty sure this is still the case.

Comment: Saved my day :). Why is that?

Comment: I think it's to enable writing in the Rails directory if your scripts need it. It's fairly safe to assume that if the config.ru file has certain permissions the rest will have them, too.

Comment: when the owner is root, it will run as nobody

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a user line into your nginx conf.
http://wiki.nginx.org/CoreModule#user

I suggest that in the future you ask server questions on ServerFault, they usually know a lot more about nginx and passenger.

Comment: If I understood correctly your answer - I have user line in my nginx.conf (see my question). And Nginx stats for this user, but passenger doesn't.

Comment: I post the question regarding Nginx and Passenger on ServerFault, but didn't get any answer. :(

Comment: Here is the question http://serverfault.com/questions/276228/nginx-passenger-redmine-403-forbidden. It is different, but I think that the problem is user rights.

Comment: hmm, well does my answer fix the problem for you?

Comment: No, doesn't. I have user line in my nginx.conf (see my question). And Nginx stats for this user, but passenger doesn't.

Comment: why cant you chown the files?