# Permission denied with Rails 3.1, paperclip gem and nginx

Tags: ruby, nginx, ruby-on-rails-3.1, paperclip

Using Rails 3.1 with the paperclip gem on nginx I get the following 500 error when attempting to upload images:

`Permission denied - /webapps/my_rails_app/public/system`

Observing the guidance offered elsewhere on this issue, I have modified my directory permissions such that

`drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data  4096 Mar 10 17:57 system`

And, it would appear, this permission structure is maintained for all public sub-directories.

Yet, having restarted nginx, the error persists.

Do I need to modify nginx.conf or take another hack at permissioning the affected directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I've run into this in the past, it's generally because the Rails application was started by a user or process that is not a part of the `www-data` group, and is not the `www-data` user.  I'd first check to confirm that the `www-data` is in fact running your app.

This can be done using `ps awwwx` and perhaps some `grep` logic to find your app in the process stack.

I might suggest that you change the directory permissions to allow any member of the `www-data` group to write to the directory as well.

Comment: This was helpful, if a little indirect, to my ultimate solution: [changing the user to start Passenger in nginx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214913/user-to-start-passenger-with-nginx)