# Nginx 500 error when uploading Paperclip image with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, nginx, passenger

I have a Rails 4.1.4 application running on Nginx, Phusion Passenger, Postgresql, and Arch Linux. I'm deploying with Capistrano.

In my Rails application I am trying to upload an image via the Paperclip gem. By default Paperclip stores images in `/public/system`. I don't want that directory to be overwritten when I redeploy, so in my `deploy.rb` I've got it set as a linked directory:

```
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system', 'public/uploads', 'public/documents')
```

Now, when I go to one of my forms and attempt to upload the image, I receive a 500 internal server error from Nginx. Checking the Nginx `error.log`, it reports:

> 2016/08/10 14:55:56 [crit] 636#0: *2 open()
>   "/home/rserver/nginx/client_body_temp/0000000002" failed (13:
>   Permission denied), ...
>
> 2016/08/10 14:55:56 [alert] 636#0: *2 Cannot stat
>   '/home/rserver/nginx/config.ru': Permission denied (errno=13); This
>   error means that the Nginx worker process (PID 636, running as UID 99)
>   does not have permission to access this file. Please read this page to
>   learn how to fix this problem:
>   https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/nginx/troubleshooting/?a=upon-accessing-the-web-app-nginx-reports-a-permission-denied-error;
>   Extra info, ...

Now, I've gone to the provided url. In summary, it says that the relevant folders do not have executable permissions, and so I need to add them. However, after I follow that instruction, there is no difference in outcome:

```
drwxr-xr-x 11 rserver rserver  4096 Jun 25 13:38 nginx
```

I did the same for my application's folder in `var`:

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 rserver root 4096 Aug 10 14:31 polyov
```

Now, I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214913/user-to-start-passenger-with-nginx), and followed it. The user running nginx and whatnot is called `rserver`, so I modified `nginx.conf` and added:

```
passenger_default_user rserver;
```

However a Passenger then Nginx then system restart have not solved the problem- the Nginx worker process is still run by `nobody` and I still cannot upload files.

Comment: Did you change permissions for `/home/rserver`  and `home` too?

Comment: @slowjack2k `/home/rserver` wasn't set properly... i guess i forgot my `-R` in `chmod`.

Comment: So I guess solved?

Comment: @slowjack2k yes. If you'd like to make your comment into an answer i'll accept it.

Comment: Not needed. But keep in mind that your webserver has access to your home folder. You have to double check permissions now.